# How to access my error fetch data with JavaScript - [[PromiseValue]]]:Object

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, es6-promise

I am trying to access an error message in my code. This is how it looks like this

```
const status = response => {
const status = response => {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

                return Promise.resolve(response)

            }

            return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))

        }                              

               fetch('/url hast been omitted', {

                   method: 'POST',

                   headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                   },

                   body: JSON.stringify({
                        email: email.value,
                        name:  name.value,
                        message:  message.value
                   })

               }).then(status).then(res => {
                
                 const response = res.json();// i did this so i can console.log the value, which i did

                  return  response;

               }).then( data => {

                 console.log('data :'+ data.errors);

               }).catch(err=>{

                 console.log(err);

               });
```

And this is my browser information when I console.log the response:

And when I log data to the console, it looks like this:

```
   data :[object Object],[object Object]
```

I don't know how to access the errors array message. It is in this  [[PromiseValue]]].

What is wrong here, how can I access this?

Comment: Use `console.log('data:', data.errors);` (you forced an object into a string, which produces `[object Object]`)

Comment: try using console.dir(data, { depth: null });

Comment: You don't need to do `return Prmise.resolve` or `Promise.reject` inside the callback function `status` for then, just simply do `return response` or simply reject with a new `error`.

Comment: .It worked. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
}).then( data => {

  console.log('data :'+ data.errors); // Change this!
  console.log(data.errors); // to this
  // Now the object is converted to a String.

}).catch(err=>{
```

Comment: Thanks. I already did that. have pushed it to my landing page.